# Firebase Realtime-database: How can I check if a user exists in the database without using firebase auth

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently building a game with `unity` and `Firebase`, but instead of using `Firebase` authentication for `Facebook`, I did it on my own.
Now when the game starts, I wanna check if the user logged-in in the past(if he exists in the database), but I can't seem to figure it out. (Also, i'm using `Push()` to generate unique `id`s).
How do I get only the data from the specific user?

I tried to get the `Facebook ID` in the start of the game and then order by child like this: (`FBid` is the `facebook` `id` variable)

```
DataSnapshot userSnapshot =
    await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                          .GetReference("Users")
                          .OrderByChild("FBid")
                          .EqualsTo(FBid)
                          .GetValueAsync();
```

but that didn't work well because I had a hard time requesting in every start the `Facebook` `id`, and what I mean by that is that when I call the `FB.API` in the start of the game I get an error :

> 400 bad request

which I tried to solve but then I realized that I don't wanna make so many api calls, I wanna do that once and save it in the database, then reuse it from the database everytime.

So, I ran out of ideas, can anyone help me get the data of the user that is playing?

Comment: "but that didn't work well because I had a hard time requesting in every start the Facebook id." I'm not sure I understand what that mean. Did you read the query results and try to process them? If so, what didn't work about it? Can you update your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Done, Hope it's clearer now (: